# Cocoa Touch - trigger a selection table view from a textfield

Tags: iphone

Hihi all,

I have a TextField (the TextField is added into the TableViewCell from code) in my first view for gender selection. Would need to trigger a second view for gender selection upon clicking on the TextField. After selected a gender from the second view, the second view should be dismissed and the selected gender value should be returned back to the active TextField in the first view.

Hope that I am clear enough on my question. This might be just a foolish question, but I am still new in cocoa touch. Thanks in advance!

:)

Comment: ok lemme try.. is there only one text field in cell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of create a second view for the gender selection, this is what I have implemented

1. When the gender textbox becomes first responder, in the textFieldShouldBeginEditing delegate, show up the gender pickerView in place of the original keyboard.
2. Upon selecting of a gender, in the pickerView didSelectRow delegate, return the selected gender to the active textbox.

:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get a selection of gender, then why is it a textbox? You could convert the selection itself directly into a text in code. Why display a text
box? Could you elaborate on what is it that you want to do. It is not so clear by your description.

Comment: it is not necessary to be a textbox, I am new to iphone dev, the textbox is just to show the selected value on screen before the user click on the continue button for further process. May you suggest a best practice on doing this? What it's required is just a gender selection.